# Let $f$ be a nonconstant polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$. Prove that $f$ takes on infinitely many values in $\mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

> Let $f$ be a nonconstant polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$. Prove that $f$ takes on infinitely many values in $\mathbb Z$.

This is a homework problem so no need to give me an immediate answer.

My general plan has been to try to prove that $f(x)$ cannot have both an upper bound and a lower bound.

One strategy I tried was using induction on the degree of f. The base case for $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x$ is very doable to show that it cannot have both upper & lower bounds. It's when you get to $\deg(f) = n$ that things start to get tricky.

The chapter of the book I'm working with, Contemporary Abstract Algebra, 8th edition, has the theorem for the division algorithm for polynomials, and as a corollary we see that $f(a)$ is the remainder of $f(x)$ when dividing by $(x - a)$. So I am assuming they want me to try using that, but I'm not sure.

I feel as though I could brute force this problem by

1. Starting with $f(b) =$ lower bound and $f(c) =$ upper bound
2. Checking if the leading term has an even/odd power
3. Checking if the leading coefficient is positive/negative

Once all those are fixed, I would have to come up with a clever value for $b$ or $c$, and then use that to show that we can't have both an upper bound and a lower bound.

What I would really love is if there is a more elegant solution using the image of the polynomial $f(Z)$ and showing some contradiction if it's finite. But nothing I've come across fits that.

Comment: But induction doesn't seems so hard, every $n+1$ degree polynomial can be written as $b+x(\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i)$, the constant doesn't matter, so you have unbounded expression times $x$, so unless $x\to0$ you have $n+1$ degree also unbounded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(X)\in\Bbb{Z}[X]$ takes on only finitely many values in $\Bbb{Z}$, then it must take one of these values (say $c$) infinitely many times. But then $f(X)-c$ has infinitely many zeroes in $\Bbb{Z}$...

Comment: The pigeon hole principle strikes again! Yea, I thought I was looking in the wrong direction while I was doing it. Thanks!